# MS Project COM: Click on a Ribbon UI button using COM

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I have 2 different .NET projects:

1) MS Project 2010 VSTO project: This project adds a custom ribbon (using XML) to MS Project's ribbon UI. There is a button on this custom ribbon (called "Push_changes"). This project has been packaged into a "VSTO package" and installed on my local machine.

2) I have another .NET console application that has a reference to MS Project Object Library (COM object). Using COM, I am able to start a new instance of MS Project 2010. As a next step, I want to be able to get to the Ribbon (specifically the one that I added in Step 1, using the VSTO project). I then want to get to the "Push_changes" button and click on it (through code).

Now I tried, going through the CommandBars collection, but it doesn't seem to contain anything related to "Ribbon". Enumerating through the CommandBars collection, I can see that there is a CommandBar called "Ribbon", but it says that it has "0" controls on it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assembly which implements Add-on with a ribbon contains a COM Visible class inherited from `Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility`.

One of public methods from that class implements that onClick action.

You can access collection of COM Add-Ons through `Application.COMAddIns` and access that Add-In by name.

Comment: melan, thank you for this reply. Can you point me to some sample code that does this?

Comment: probably this page may help: http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/06/23/exposing-c-classes-thru-interop.aspx